# How to Align a Link HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have tried to do the following, as well as using the align only with the `<a>` href and `<img>` tags, yet I still cannot align the clickable image to the center of the page.

```html
<a href="next.html" align="middle">
   <img src="tlbr.png" align="middle">
</a>
```

The float tag also does not work in any way I have tried, since, as far as I am aware, there is no way to float to center.

Any solution, directly in HTML or in the CSS, would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the demo and try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzs75c9y/1/)**

```
a img {
   margin:0 auto;    
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your CSS:

```
a img{
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jt5k0rfo/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block; text-align: center;` to href link. And try.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should set width and display for your `a` element and them display the `img` tang and using `margin: 0 auto` to set the image in center:

```html
<a href="#" align="middle" style="width: 100%; display: block; background: #ccc;">
   <img src="http://caster.ir/public/images/logo.png" align="middle" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` tag align Attribute aligns the image vertically with respect to the line.  The `<a>` tag does not recognise the align attribute.

If you are trying to centre an image horizontally then you might want to try using the following:

```
<a href="next.html">
   <img id="myImg" src="tlbr.png" />
</a>
```

Then in your CSS stylesheet:

```
#myImg {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add a `<p>` tag and then align it. For example:

```
<a href="link.com">
   <p align="center">Hello World!</p>
</a>
```